# GitLab CI build sub-projects and deploy them to kubernetes separately

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, kubernetes, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci

If I have a GitLab project, which contains several sub-folders:

- two with java code (from java:alpine, to compile with maven and build containers)
- one with nginx config (from openresty:alpine, to build a web server container)

Every of sub-projects has a Dockerfile, deployment.yml, and gitlab-ci.yml.

deployment.yml is similar for every of sub-folders in the project, as all the sub-projects results to a single multi-container kubernetes pod.

How can I set up this project to build and deploy to kubernetes only the container, which I edited by the last commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a dirty hack like setting several build blocks in .gitlab-ci.yml for every sub-project and setting for every on them `only` parameter:

```
maven-build-akka:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: build
  only:
    - /^akka-.*$/
  script:
    - cd akka
    - mvn package -B --settings ../settings.xml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - akka/target/*.jar
```

And so for `docker build stage`.

After that, if I push a tag like `akka-1.0.3`, appropriate pipeline jobs would be launched.

But, there's an issue with only one name for images in GitLab CI registry for a single project, so you should push images somewhere else (GCR, etc.)

Comment: shouldn't `only` check for branch (not filepath)?